# Using Leibniz' Transmutation theorem

Tags: calculus, integration

I was asked the following:

> Given the curve $y^q=x^p    (q>p>0)$ show using the transmutation theorem that $\int^{x_0}_0ydx=\frac{qx_0y_0}{p+q}$

Note that from $y^q=x^p$ it follows that $q \frac{dy}{y}=p\frac{dx}{x}$. Therefore, $z=y-x\frac{dy}{dx}=(\frac{q-p}{q})y$.

I'm not really sure how show this. Here is my work:

The transmutation theorem states: $\int^{x_0}_0ydx=\frac12(x_0y_0+\int^{x_0}_0z dx)$

We know z in this case and so can write it out like this: $\int^{x_0}_0ydx=\frac12(x_0y_0+\int^{x_0}_0y-x\frac{dy}{dx} dx)=\frac12(x_0y_0+\int^{x_0}_0y-x dx)$

$=\frac12(x_0y_0+yx_0-\frac{x_0^2}{2})$

Am I going about this right? How can I proceed from here?

*Edit: As I've been working on this problem, I was able to use the different values of z to solve for $x_0$. I got $x_0=\frac{2py}{q}$

We can plug this into the equation above to get $\frac12(\frac{2py}{q}y_0+y\frac{2py}{q}-\frac{(\frac{2py}{q})^2}{2})$

I can further multiply this out: $\frac{py}{q}(y_0+y-\frac{py}{q})$

This in turn can be rewritten as $\frac{2x_0(p+q)}{(p+q)}(y_0+y-\frac{py}{q})$.

I see how this is getting me closer to my goal, but I don't see how to get all the way there.

Answer (score 1):

The transmutation theorem is equivalent algebraically to integration by parts.  A detailed geometric explanation by Dennis and Addington appears [here](http://www.quadrivium.info/MathInt/Notes/Transmutation.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

When $y$ is a strictly convex function of $x$ then $x\mapsto y'(x)$ is
injective and
$$
z=y-x\,p\,,\quad p=y'(x)
$$
can be viewed as a function of the conjugate variable $p\,.$ This $z(p)$ is known as the Legendre transform.

However, *Leibniz* did not assume that $y$ is strictly convex and considered
$$
z(x)=y(x)-x\,y'(x)
$$
as a function of $x\,.$ Then, with integration by parts, as Mikhail Katz pointed out,
\begin{align}
\int_a^bz(x)\,dx&=\int_a^b y(x)\,dx-\int_a^bx\,y'(x)\,dx
=\int_a^b y(x)\,dx+\int_a^by(x)\,dx-\Big[x\,y(x)\Big]_{x=a}^{x=b}\,.
\end{align}
Or,
$$
\int_a^by(x)\,dx=\frac12\int_a^bz(x)\,dx+\frac12\Big[x\,y(x)\Big]_{x=a}^{x=b}\,.
$$

Comment: Kurt, do you have sources that would discuss this other than the Dennis-Addington text I linked?

Comment: @MikhailKatz As far as I remember I only was able to google [this](https://www.tu-braunschweig.de/fileadmin/Redaktionsgruppen/Institute_Fakultaet_1/IPDE/sonar/v121.pdf). It is a nice topic of which I never heard before and I think it deserves more attention.

Comment: This discussion seems to be reproduced in Sonar's book from '21, on pages 414-415.

Comment: This must be the book Thomas Sonar, *3000 Years of Analysis*.

Comment: I get stuck checking an example that occurs in Leibniz.  He starts with a semicircular arc passing through the origin, and ends up with the inverse of the function $\frac1{1+x^2}$ (I guess I should use a different letter there in place of $x$).  How does one check this?

Comment: @MikhailKatz . Need more details. Of Sonar's book I found only incomplete parts in google. Page 414 was missing even in the original German edition.

Comment: Sonar starts with the half-circle equation $y=\sqrt{2x-x^2}$, finds
that $z=y-x\frac{1-x}{y}=\sqrt{\frac{x}{2-x}}$, and therefore
$x=\frac{2z^2}{1+z^2}$.  This is similar but not identical to the
transmutated function that appears in Leibniz, which seems to be
$\frac{2}{1+z^2}$.  Leibniz's function makes more sense because it
tends to zero sufficiently rapidly when $z\to\infty$ so that the area
under the curve is finite, and equal to the area under the semicircle
(up to a factor of $2$).  But how do you do the calculation to get
Leibniz's result?

Comment: For $y=\sqrt{2x-x^2}$ I get (with the formulas in the answer) $z=\sqrt{\frac{x}{2-x}}\,.$ As I said: I don't have full access to Sonar's book. Therefore I have no idea what else Leibniz might have done.

Comment: Kurt, Sonar gets the same answer as you do, but it is not the same as the one given by Leibniz in the proof of proposition 11 in De Quadratura Arithmetica.  Perhaps Leibniz applies two consecutive transmutations there; I haven't figured out what is going on yet.  There is a French translation by Parmentier online, which also has the Latin original.  If you don't read either, there is a Latin-German edition by Knobloch..

Comment: @MikhailKatz I have little motivation to google further what Leibniz might have done. If you want help I recommend that you transcribe it in mathJax in a new post in MSE. The language doe not matter to me.

Comment: Kurt, Leibniz's proposition is embedded in a sequence of propositions so I would have to do a whole lot of typing.  I noticed that the online Parmentier does not include one of the pages of the proof of Proposition 11, unfortunately.  However, I can send you a pdf of the relevant pages  if you are interested.

Comment: No need to send me pdfs. Just found in JSTOR the article *Newton's Teaser* by Nick Mackinnon, in Mathematical Gazette, Vol. 76, No. 475, Mar. 1992. It seems like he is unravelling in modern integral notation a couple of Newton-Leibniz letters on exactly that matter.

Comment: Kurt, thanks for the hint.  I will try to look up Machinnon's article.  Notice, however, that while transmutation is already mentioned in the letter to Newton as per Sonar, the manuscript *De Quadratura Arithmetica* that received so much attention recently was written later, and does not seem to have exactly the same argument.